# C# exercise, output is not right

Tags: c#

The purpose of the exercise is to check whether a point is on the sides of a 2D rectangle. I got some of the output right. But I have no idea why the final "else" clause seems to be ignored when it should be printed.

Source Code:

```
using System;

class pointOnBorder
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var x1 = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        var y1 = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        var x2 = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        var y2 = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        var x = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        var y = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (x1 < x2 && y1 < y2)
        {
            if (x == x1 || x == x2) 
            {
                if (y >= y1 && y <= y2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Border");
                }
            }
            else if (y == y1 || y == y2)
            {
                if (x >= x1 && x <= x2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Border"        );
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("Inside  / Outside");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: there is nothing wrong with the "Border" output.

I want to print "Inside / Outside" but it didn't seem to work out (I get empty output). I have asked elsewhere and there was a suggestion that my "else" may be under the first "if", as far as a can see this is not the case and therefore I don't see a reason why my final "else" clause is ignored.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You can step into debugger and find out exactly what's going on

Comment: Your main if has 3 segments, if it goes into segment one but isnt (y >= y1 && y <= y2) then nothing will be ouputted.. same with segment two.. if the inner if isnt met nothing happens

Comment: think about it more. This should be 1 if/else, not 5. Sketch a picture with x1/x2/y1/y2 labels and write down what it means for something to be on the border. There are 4 edges, you prbably need 4 expression ORed, e.g. (x is on X1 AND y is between Y1 and Y2) OR .....

Comment: It should go through the last else when x is not x1 or x2 and y is not y1 or y2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to emphasize that this is not how I would write this functionality. I agree that your code is overly complicated, but understanding that you may want your code fixed so you can see what's wrong, rather than completely re-written, here is your code fixed:

```
class pointOnBorder{
   static void Main(){
      var x1 = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
      var y1 = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

      var x2 = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
      var y2 = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

      var x = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
      var y = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

      if (x1 < x2 && y1 < y2)
      {
         if (x == x1 || x == x2)
         {
            if (y >= y1 && y <= y2)
            {
               Console.WriteLine("Border");
            }
            else
            {
               Console.Write("Inside  / Outside");
            }
         }
         else if (y == y1 || y == y2)
         {
            if (x >= x1 && x <= x2)
            {
               Console.WriteLine("Border");
            }
            else
            {
               Console.Write("Inside  / Outside");
            }
         }
         else
         {
            Console.Write("Inside  / Outside");
         }
      }
      else{
         Console.Write("Bad rectangle specification.");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: @CosmicSalad - You're welcome.  If you are satisfied, could you please accept one of the answers?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cover all possible cases, each `if` should have its corresponding `else`. And I see only 3 `else` for 5 `if`.

Comment: Thanks for the replies people!

Answer (score 0):

you can try by closing the bracket of `if` above the `else if` keyword OR instead of `else if` write `else`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is over complicated.

I would simplify it to this:

```
// this is a conditional assignment -
// if the condition is true, pointLocation would be assigned with "Border".
// if it's false, it will be assigned with "Inside  / Outside". 
// It's a short way to write if...else statements - condition ? true : false ;
var pointLocation = (
   (IsValueEqualToStartOrToStop(x1, x2, x) && IsValueBetweenStartAndStop(y1, y2, y)) || 
   (IsValueEqualToStartOrToStop(y1, y2, y) && IsValueBetweenStartAndStop(x1, x2, x))) ? "Border" : "Inside  / Outside";

    Console.WriteLine(pointLocation);

// this method checks that the value is equal to start or to stop. 
bool IsValueEqualToStartOrToStop(decimal start, decimal stop, decimal value)
{
    return value == start || value == stop;
}

// this method checks if the value is between start and stop
bool IsValueBetweenStartAndStop(decimal start, decimal  stop, decimal  value)
{
    return (start < stop && start <= value && value <= stop) || 
           (start > stop && start >= value && value >= stop); value 
}
```

Comment: Zohar Peled your solution is a little too advanced for me yet. :p

Comment: It's actually quite simple. I've edited my answer with some comments and renames, Let me know if it's still unclear.